# How can I use _lodash debounce with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

It was suggested I could use the following:

```
$wmdInput.on('keyup', _.debounce(function () {
    var rawContent = $wmdInput.val();
    scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(rawContent);
    });
}), 300);
```

However this gives a message: Uncaught TypeError: Object 500 has no method 'apply'  from jQuery.

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

As an FYI it was also suggested I could use the following:

```
var promise;
$wmdInput.on('keyup', function () {
    $timeout.cancel(promise);
    promise = $timeout(function() {
        var rawContent = $wmdInput.val();
        ngModel.$setViewValue(rawContent);
    }, 2000);
});
```

I would appreciate comments from the AngularJS experts here. Would the second code work as well as using _lodash?  I noticed a lot of posts on github so I hope to see something implemented in the core AngularJS soon.

Comment: Just eyeballing the second snippet and it looks as if it should work. However using debounce is more expressive of what you're trying to achieve e.g $wmdInput.on( 'keyup', _.debounce( processInput, 300 )) is a bit clearer than using a promise variable and cancel and setting the timeout again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (now deleted) answer from @Satpal was correct: you are passing the timeout value (`300`) as an argument to `$wmdInput.on`, and not `_.debounce`.

So try this:

```
$wmdInput.on('keyup', _.debounce(function () {
  var rawContent = $wmdInput.val();
  scope.$apply(function () {
    ngModel.$setViewValue(rawContent);
  });
}, 300));
```

Comment: I got scared by Samantha J's comment. I didn't want to indulge in long conversation as yesterday. Thus deleted answer which I knew was correct. Thanks anyway for obivous